# Why are the transfer and approve functions payable in the ERC-721 spec?

Tags: payable, erc-721

In [the ERC-721 spec interface](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md), the functions `safeTransferFrom`, `transferFrom` and `approve` all have the `payable` modifier. What is the reason for this? As far as I can tell, none of these functions require it, and I'm not sure what I should be doing with the value.

`function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes data) external payable;`

`function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external payable;`

`function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external payable;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears the answer is to do with mutability, from the "Caveats" section of the ERC721 spec,

> Solidity issue #3412: The above interfaces include explicit mutability guarantees for each function. Mutability guarantees are, in order weak to strong: *payable*, implicit nonpayable, *view*, and *pure*. Your implementation MUST meet the mutability guarantee in this interface and you MAY meet a stronger guarantee. For example, a payable function in this interface may be implemented as nonpayble (no state mutability specified) in your contract. We expect a later Solidity release will allow your stricter contract to inherit from this interface, but a workaround for version 0.4.20 is that you can edit this interface to add stricter mutability before inheriting from your contract.

So the functions are marked *payable* as a way of explicitly not requiring that these functions are *view* or *pure*.

Here's a link to [the discussion of issue #3412](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3412), which discusses mutability guarantees.